# If $f,g$ are simple measurable functions, show that $f+g$ and $f\,g$ are too

Tags: real-analysis

This homework problem involves showing that if $f,g$ are measurable **simple** functions, then so is $f+g$ and $f\,g$ - without using:

1) $\{x \in A: (f+g)(x) < t\} = \bigcup_{r\in\mathbb{Q}} \left[ \{x\in A: f(x) < r\} \cap \{x \in A: g(x) < t-r\} \right]$, for $(X,\mathcal{A})$, $X \supseteq A \in \mathcal{A}$, $f,g$ are $[0,{}^+\infty]$-valued measurable functions on $A$.

2) using $f-g$ as $f+(-1)\,g$, **or** $f^2$ proofs whereby one uses the set $\{x\in A: f^2(x) < t \} = \{ x\in A: -\sqrt{t} < f(x) < \sqrt{t} \}$

**(I hope this is clear!)**

---

So I believe (think) that a simple function is: $f := \sum_{k=1}^n\,a_k\,\chi_{E_k}$, where $E_k = f^{-1}(\{a_k\}) \in \mathcal{A}$ (though I don't think it has to belong to the algebra).

I am supposed to show these claims without using the two enumerations above in two different ways, one using **simple** functions, and the other using:

3) $f \vee g := \max(f(x),g(x)) \leftrightarrow \{x \in A: (f \vee g)(x) \leq t\} = \{x \in A: f(x) \leq t\} \cap \{x \in A: g(x) \leq t \}$

4) $f \wedge g \cdots \{ \} = \{ \} \cup \{ \}$

5) This theorem claims: $(X,\mathcal{A})$ - measurable space, $X \supseteq A \in \mathcal{A}$, $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of $[{}^-\infty,{}^+\infty]$-valued measurable functions on $A$. Then (a) functions $\sup_n f_n$ and $\inf_n f_n$ are measurable, (b) $\limsup_n f_n$ and $\liminf_n f_n$ are measurable, and (c) $\lim_n f_n$ is measurable, with a domain where $\limsup_n f_n = \liminf_n f_n$

6) The sets $A_{n,k} = \{x \in A: \frac{k-1}{2^n} \leq f(x) < \frac{k}{2^n} \}$, which is like a scaled (to $n$) `largest integer function' that is more and more refined with increasing $n$

These are utilized in the claim: $(X,\mathcal{A})$ - measurable space, $X \supseteq A \in \mathcal{A}$, and $f$ be a $[0,+\infty]$-valued measurable function on $A$. Then there is a sequence $\{f_n\}$ of $[0,+\infty]$-valued **simple** measurable functions on $A$ that satisfy (1) $f_1(x) \leq f_2(x) \leq \cdots$ and (2) $f(x) = \lim_n f_n(x)$, at each $x \in A$.

---

I am pretty clear on 3,4,5, and 6; as well as how 1 and 2 work and why the question doesn't want them used (it would be too easy to quote a theorem). Unfortunately, I just don't know how to start - in either direction.

For the **simple** way, I was thinking of something like $$ (f+g)(x) = \sum_{n=1}^k\,(a_k^f+a_k^g)\,\chi_{E_k} = \cdots, $$  $$ (f\,g)(x) = \sum_{n=1}^k\,(a_k^f\,a_k^g)\,\chi_{E_k} = \cdots  .$$

As for the way utilizing 3-6 I have no clue!

This is question 5 out of Donald Cohn's book *Measure Theory*, Chapter 2 section 1 - page 57 - if interested.

I usually ask math.stackexchange because the answers are not given and I eventually get to understand the question - that is what I am hoping for now too!

Thanks much!

Comment: (i) Please don't YELL (all caps is yelling); (2) there is no need to "sign" your messages with your name, since your user name always appears in the bottom right.

Comment: Two good points I will keep in mind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that your approach is too complicated to prove this for simple functions.

Given $E_1,E_2,\ldots E_n$ a simple function $f$ has the form $$f=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\chi_{E_k},$$
where $a_1,\ldots,a_n$ are real numbers. I suggest the following exercises:

1. Prove that there exist $b_1,b_2,\ldots ,b_m$, pairwise distinct, and $A_1,\ldots ,A_m$, pairwise disjoint, such that $$f=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\chi_{E_k}=\sum_{k=1}^mb_k\chi_{A_k}.$$
2. Prove that if $f=a\chi_{E}$, $a\neq 0$, then $f$ is measurable if and only if $A$ is measurable (note that if $a=0$, $f$ is constant and then measurable).
3. Prove that any simple function $f=\sum_{k=1}^na_k\chi_{E_k},$ is measurable if and only if $E_1,\ldots,E_n$ are measurable sets.
4. Prove that sum of simple functions is a simple function, prove that the product of simple functions is a simple function.

To prove that the sum of measurable simple functions is simple, consider the sets that you get when finishing 4. Same thing for the product. Hope this helps.

Comment: @nate: feel free in ask me if something is unclear.

Comment: <sub> @leo thanks - a lot of thought later and i think i got it! </sub>

Comment: you are welcome @nate